# How to expand the recovery partition of my hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1

[Disk Management pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76yJP.jpg)
I want to add/allocate free space to the final partition in the image above (the 14gb one). How would I do so?

The intent is to test if a larger recovery partition will fix a space error I am getting when I try to recover a backup using lenovo one key recovery on my lenovo ideapad y510p.

Comment: You can use a third party partition tool to do so. It’s unlikely to solve anything. Space on the recovery drive doesn’t come in to play during a recovery. I’d recommend downloading and creating your own installation media with the media creation tool and blowing away all the Lenovo stuff. Using the Lenovo recovery is just putting an unpatched operation system with bloatware back on your computer.

Comment: I do not recommend that you change Lenovo's one key recovery feature because this may be problematic and cannot be used. If you want to change the recovery partition, I think you can also try diskpart command.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways to do what you're after

- Open the **Run** dialog from the (start) menu, and type `Diskmgmt.msc`. Once open. Right-click on the Volume (partition) you want to make larger, and choose "**Extend Volume**", and grow it as large as you're able, or want. Simple as that.
- Another option would be to use a 3rd party application. The only one I'm willing to recommend here, is one that permits burning to a DVD/USB flash drive. Which allows booting into a (Linux) desktop environment, with the Partition manager already running. It's point-and-click, and very easy to understand. Even for the "less technical" crowd. It's called [Gparted](https://gparted.org/). It offers, and explains how, and which image to download. As well as how to burn, or create a bootable USB stick.

Either option will accomplish your goal.

Comment: Option one doesn't work for the recovery partitions (right click only displays "help" as an option), I've been using that method for the other partitions already.